# Getting the text of a webpage with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, beautifulsoup

BeautifulSoup, a python library, has a function called get_text() that can take a parsed HTML page, such as this: https://pastebin.com/DJwA3S5P

and extract all of the text from it, thus turning it into this: https://pastebin.com/qMqrj8RS

Here's another example of what the function can do:

If given the following:

```
<span id="sm_flash_225" onclick="sm_flash_process('bail', this,1)" onmouseover="sm_flash_add('bail', this, 1);" onmouseout="sm_flash_remove('bail', this, 1);">bail</span>
```

BeautifulSoup's get_text() function will simply turn it into:
`bail`

In other words, it takes `<span id ="some_id" more random stuff...>text</span>` and turns into into `text`.

I have the HTML file of a website that is contained as one large formatted string. I would like to write the Javascript equivalent of BeautifulSoup's get_text() in order to only get the text of the webpage. I'm fine with using any third party library etc., I don't want to re-invent the wheel. However, it's worth noting that I'm writing this in the context of a Chrome/Firefox web extension, so I don't believe I can use every single 3rd party library.

I acquired the HTML file with the following code:

```
fetch(url)
.then((resp) => resp.text())
.then(function (data) { 
    //get the text of the webpage by 
    //mimicking Beautiful Soup's get_text() function        
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safer not to insert live HTML (and JS) from another site onto your own. Use DOMParser instead:

```js
fetch("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/stackoverflow.com", )
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(responseText => {
    const responseDocument = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(responseText, 'text/html');
    console.log(responseDocument.head.textContent);
    console.log(responseDocument.body.textContent);
  });
```

Comment: Quick question - you say that it's safer not to insert live HTML from another site onto your own. But does xianshenglu's solution actually involve inserting html into a site? I.e - does `document.CreateElement("div")` actually insert a `div` into a live site? This is all code for a chrome/firefox web extension, so I don't think I'm actually modifying any website. Apologies if this question is silly - I'm relatively new to Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
fetch("test.html")
  .then(data => data.text())
  .then(text => {
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = text;
    console.log(div.textContent);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Can you explain what your code does?

Comment: @Roymunson,just an interface provided by html,you can create a html element by document.createElement and set it's content by innerHTML and get the text by ele.textContent